# How to know record has been updated successfully in php

Tags: php, mysql

`$sql = "UPDATE...."`;

```
if(mysql_query($sql))
    {
        $_SESSION['Trans']="COMMIT";
        header("location:result.php");
        exit;
    }
    else 
        {
            $_SESSION['Trans']="FAIL";
            $_SESSION['errors'] = "Error: Sorry! We are unable to update your Profile, Please contact to PNP HelpDesk.";
            header("location:result.php");
            exit;
        }//end  IF
```

**data is getting updated then why compiler is not coming inside IF condition.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysql_query` only returns FALSE on an error condition, rather than if no rows have been updated.

To see if anything has been updated, use [`mysql_affected_rows`](http://www.php.net/mysql_affected_rows), e.g.:

```
$sql = 'UPDATE ....';
mysql_query($sql);
if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0) { 
  // Success
} else {
  // Failure
}
```

Comment: Although it doesn't,

For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc, mysql_query() returns TRUE  on success or FALSE on error. 

But I would still assign it to a variable and test that, perhaps with a more implicit `if($result === true)`

Comment: @DavidYell So it does. I had a cursory check of the docs and the return type is given as `resource` rather than `mixed`, so didn't read on. Either way though, an UPDATE that affects no rows is still "successful", so you still need `mysql_affected_rows` :)

Comment: it returns FALSE on an error. No row updated is no error but from the database POV valid correct behavior, depending on the data and where clause.

Comment: @Lisa Are you sure your query isn't erroring? Try `mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());`